# Emailing about Code freeze

Tags: freeze, code-freeze

I need to notify my team about the approaching code freeze, So what all details should be mentioned in the mail? I want to prepare a standard template.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually mention the following items:

1. Code freeze date (date/time of last commit).
2. Name of the branch that'll be used for the freeze.
3. Grace period length for critical in-progress issue.
4. What release/build is this for.
5. Feature set of such release.